# SVN list revision parameter range not allowed

Tags: svn

I'm trying to get information about an specific svn repository directory within a given time range (or revision range) therefore I'm "trying" to use **svn list**.

```
svn list https://svn/to/repo/dir -r {2016-01-01}:{2016-08-01} --xml
Output: svn: E195008: Revision range is not allowed
```

svn help list:

```
-r [--revision] ARG      : ARG (some commands also take ARG1:ARG2 range)
                            A revision argument can be one of:
                               NUMBER       revision number
                               '{' DATE '}' revision at start of the date
```

Its the same as with **svn log**,which is working but i need **svn list**. Thanks for any help on this issue.

Comment: Why do you need `svn list` to display a revision range? Do you understand what `svn list` is supposed to show?

Comment: svn list with param xml gives me a list in an xml file with all the directories (in this case releases) with name, revision, author and the date. exactly the thing i need. If there is something else like this i'm also fine.

Comment: `ls` is a snapshot of repo-tree "at the time of ...". Inside range tree can be changed, what you expect to see in this case?!

Comment: I excpect to see the directories from my given range (in this case time range) as commited. like with *svn log -r* were i get the log within the given range.

Comment: just dont get why its within the help (svn help list), actually totally the same as in the help for log (svn help log) but seems to function different.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get *slice* of repo with range - it's also haven't any physical|logical sense

"...**some commands** also take..." mean "*check every command for possibility of ..."* - you done it

Comment: sorry i dont understand your answer. "You can't get slice of repo with range" the help says i can, or am i getting it wrong?